# MS Access VBA - Retain changes made to a report's size/control sizes while in Layout View

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following (simplified) VBA code that demonstrates the problem while resizing a report and its controls from a module. To reproduce, create a new blank database, add a table and a report, then add this code into a new module:

```
Public Sub ResizeReport()
    Dim rr as Report
    Dim cc as Control

    Set rr = Screen.ActiveReport

    For Each cc in rr.Controls
         cc.Width = 1 * 1440
    Next

    rr.Width = 5 * 1440
End Sub
```

If I open a report in `Design View` and run the macro, the changes stay when I change to other views (such as `Report View`, `Layout View`, or `Print Preview`). However, if I open the report in `Layout View` and run the macro, the report and its controls are resized, but as soon as I change the view mode, the report reverts to its state before the resize.

Please note that this issue does not occur if I manually resize the report/controls using drag handles or the `Property Sheet` while in `Layout View`.

Is there a command I need to issue after resizing the report/controls from VBA while in `Layout View` to get the changes to stick? Or should I be resizing the report/controls using different VBA commands?

I am using MS Access 2010.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Thank you** for the short yet detailed question and functioning "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)xample".  I may need to refer other newbies to this question as an example of a perfect question. +1 for that even though the answer seems obvious.</sub>  :)

---

You should **save** the report before changing it's view.

```
DoCmd.Save acReport, rr.Name
```

This will force the changes to "stick".  The logic behind the report reverting to its previous state when changing view is to allow for dynamic, temporary changes at runtime, without permanently affecting the report.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`DoCmd.Save` Method** (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-save-method-access)
- MSDN : [**Set Form, Report, and Control Properties in Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/access-vba/articles/set-form-report-and-control-properties-in-code)

Comment: +1 Haha thanks. I've been a registered user on SO for 5 years, so I have a pretty good idea of how to format a question well.

Comment: Is there any way to get the changes to stick without saving? I've noticed that if I manually edit a control in `Layout View` before or after running the macro, the changes stick when switching views. Since these macros are attached to a custom ribbon that is used by end users to resize controls, I don't want to be arbitrarily saving the report. (What if they don't like the changes they've made to a report and don't want to save it? They can't do that if the macros save changes when used)